# Is there any documentation for the wiki markup for a Sharepoint wiki?

Tags: sharepoint, wiki

I am looking for a list of markups that the Sharepoint Wiki (3.0) supports.  The starter page they give you when you first start a wiki shows how to use the "[[ ]]" tags to create links, but I am looking for a complete list of supported markup, but cannot find it anywhere.  I've been all over the [Microsoft Office site](http://office.microsoft.com), I've looked in the included help in Sharepoint.  I'm starting to think that the only markup they support are the "[[ ]]" tags.

Things I'd like to be able to do, for example, would be to embed a date, like the last updated date in the page somewhere, or how to format external links, etc.  Is there a way to easily find "orphaned" pages - pages that do not have any incoming links?  Is there a way to find pages that need to be created - if I create a [[link]] to a new page, but don't create the new page, can I get a list of those?  I am finding 0 documentation.

Any suggestions on a good resource for Sharepoint wikis?

Thanks in advance!

Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some notes at this Stackoverflow question:
[Does SharePoint in any way support Wiki markup languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719427/does-sharepoint-in-any-way-support-wiki-markup-languages)

There is also this [general SharePoint forum on TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/threads).

Comment: Great - it says: 'Most commonly the "[[page]]" markup is the only utilized wiki markup in SharePoint wikis'.  So in other words, Sharepoint Wikis are just WYSIWYG pages with the capability to link to each other.  *sigh*

Comment: @Brian, Well, it also says look at codeplex link. Did you?

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but it looks like the correct answer :)

Comment: @nik - Yep, I am looking at that link - however, I'm not a Sharepoint admin or anything, so I'm thinking it won't be a solution for me - but I will dig in and check it out a bit - it has some of the functions I am hoping for!

Answer (score 10):

I'm the program manager responsible for wikis in SharePoint.

Correct - [[ for links is the only syntax SharePoint wikis support in both 2007 and 2010

Comment: Well that's pretty cool that you are a SuperUser user :)  Thanks for the info - it's good to know for sure rather than hunting everywhere just in case.

The addition of the wiki in SharePoint is a great step!  (we just migrated from an older version of SP, so I was happy to have wikis in this version).

Again, I appreciate your answer - good to hear it straight from the source!

Comment: Does anyone know about any SP addons which might handle additional markup?  I would like to be able to paste Markdown or MediaWiki markup into SP.